# How can i query in "mulitple" many to many tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables with a many-to-many relationships

```
CREATE TABLE plate(
   pid integer NOT NULL,
   pname text
);

CREATE TABLE vegetables(
   vid integer NOT NULL,
   vname text
); 

CREATE TABLE meat(
       mid integer NOT NULL,
       mname text
    );
```

Many to Many relationship of the three tables:

```
+------+-----+
| pid  | vid |
+------+-----+
|   1  |  13 |
|   1  |  12 |
|   2  |  12 |
+------------+
```

and:

```
+-------+---+
| pid   |mid|
+-------+---+
|     1 | 2 | 
|     1 | 3 |
|     2 | 3 |
+-------+---+
```

The `**query**` i need is to check :

when the user enter the ingrediants of the plate,

example:

```
vid"13","12"
```

and

```
mid"2","3"
```

then the query will check wether the ingrediants can form a plate or not, by checking the many to many relationship table.
i tried using the IN statment, but find no results

any help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to find plates having all the meats and then plates having all the vegetables. Once you have those simply process a `JOIN` to obtain an intersect.

```
select pid
from
(
  -- plates having all the meats
  select pid
  from platemeat pm
  where pm.mid in (12,13)
  group by pid
  having count(distinct mid) = 2
) t1
join
(
  -- plates having all the vegetables
  select pid
  from plateveget pv
  where pv.vid in (2,3)
  group by pid
  having count(distinct vid) = 2
) t2 on t1.pid = t2.pid
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, i am having syntax error despite modifying your query, i have a made a quick demonstration database, please have a look [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b3PdT8hd3953SpShkW7aaXj_tEwrlvZ4/view?usp=sharing)